# determinant and submatrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

[image]

I'm trying to see how can we get that Laplace expansion in terms of the first $p$ rows will give us $\det A=0$. Is it a proof by induction over the size of the matrix or just a direct observation?

I know that the Laplace expansion is given by
$\det A=\sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^{i+1}a_{i1}\det A_{i1}$. But form this, I cannot see why $\det A=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the confusion here stems from ambiguity in what is meant by ''Laplace expansion''.

Initially, I thought the argument was implicitly using induction: if $p \geq q$ and we take the expansion of the determinant along the first column, using the formula given in the question, then the first $p$ terms are 0 immediately and the following terms should be 0 by some appropriate induction argument.

However,  ''Laplace expansion'' can in fact describe a process of computing the determinant that is *more general* than expanding along a single row or column: we can instead expand along 2 rows (or 2 columns, or 3 rows, etc.) in which we take a sum over all $2\times2$ minors of the 2 chosen rows, where each term up to sign is the $2\times 2$ determinant times the complementary $(n-2)\times(n-2)$ determinant (or ''cofactor'').
An example calculation is given on the [wikipedia page for Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion#Laplace_expansion_of_a_determinant_by_complementary_minors).

Using this interpretation of ''Laplace expansion'', each term must equal 0 because there is a row (or column) of all zeros in each minor, so the corresponding determinant is 0, and no induction is needed.

Comment: Good point! Thank you so much

Comment: no problem! do you mind "accepting" the answer if it's what you were looking for? no worries if it's not, just curious if there's more to the question